# Immutable.js turn nested array in immutable Map

Tags: javascript, arrays, immutable.js

I don't get a solution about the following problem. I hope this will be useful for some others developpers. I'm trying to learn about Immutable.js. I was writing a test and a function, but I don't get the desired result and I don't understand how I should do it...

-> I have the nested array members
-> what should I put in the following function to turn that array of the test into an immutable nested map?
-> what should I expect as a result?

I have this function:

```
import {List, Map, fromJS} from 'immutable';

export function setInitial(state, infos, members) {
  return state.set('infos', Map(infos))
              .set('members', ?????(members));
}
```

...and this test...

```
import {List, Map} from 'immutable';
import {expect} from 'chai';

import {setInitial,
        addAtListOfMembers,
        removeAtListOfMembers
        } from '../src/core';

describe('application logic', () => {

    describe('setInitial', () => {

        it('charge the infos of the laboratory', () => {
          const state = Map();
          const infos = {
            id:1,
            laboName: 'Magenta Service',
            phone: '+331650042958',
            mail: 'email@magentaservice.fr',
            date: '12/5/2014'
          };

        const members = [
            {
                id:1,
                userName:'René',
                date:'12/02/2016'
            },
            {
                id:2,
                userName:'Jean',
                date:'10/03/2016'
            }
         ];

          const nextState = setInitial(state, infos, members);
          expect(nextState).to.equal(Map({
            infos : Map({
                id:1,
                laboName: 'Magenta Service',
                phone: '+331650042958',
                mail: 'email@magentaservice.fr',
                date: '12/5/2014'
              }),

           // =>MAYBE ???

            members: List.of(
                Map({
                    id:1,
                    userName:'René',
                    date:'12/02/2016'
                }),
                Map({
                    id:2,
                    userName:'Jean',
                    date:'10/03/2016'
                })
              );
          }));
        });
    });
});
```

Thank you in advance for your answer!

Comment: Have you tried [`chai-immutable`](https://github.com/astorije/chai-immutable)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Immutable.fromJS()` should do what you want.